Parameters of a method defined in an interface according to another interface
I want to have the parameters of a method that is part of an interface adhere to another interface.
Consider this IOrderBuilder interface which I use to build Order object from a class that is implementing it.
interface IOrderBuilder {
  setCustomer({ customerId }: { customerId: string; }): Order;
  // ...other methods
  
  setShippingAddress(address: IAddress): Order;

  // ...other methods
}

IAddress is also an interface -
interface IAddress {
  name: string;
  addressLine1: string;
  addressLine2: string;
  landmark: string;
  city: string;
  state: string;
  pincode: number;
}

Now what I want is to have an interface let's say IShippingAddressParams, properties of whose are used as types for parameters of setShippingAddress method.
When I do it like this -
interface IShippingAddressParams {
  address: IAddress;
}

interface IOrderBuilder {
  setCustomer({ customerId }: { customerId: string; }): Order;
  // ...other methods
  
  setShippingAddress(params: IShippingAddressParams): Order;

  // ...other methods
}

In this case, I would need to pass an object while defining my setShippingAddress method like this - setShippingAddress(shippingParams: {address: IAddress}) {...}.
Instead, what I want is to be able to pass address directly like this - setShippingAddress(address: IAddress) {...}.

You'll want to use a named tuple type and a rest parameter. They're ugly to work with though. Why do you need to declare IShippingAddressParams separately in the first place?

Thanks for your input. Answering your question, let's say if I have many parameters of the function. I would want to collectively represent them a separate interface rather than mentioning them all in my main interface. Actually, my example with IShippingAddressParams is quite bad w.r.t the thing that I am asking. But I was just wondering if it was possible or not.

Please [edit] this question to be a [mre] that shows a use case with at least two parameters. I'm pretty sure this is impossible without an extra name-to-position mapping, but without a [mre] I can't tell (after all, you can just write IShippingAddressParams[keyof IShippingAddressParams] to get IAddress because there's only one thing in there. Indeed, as asked, you could just write IAddress yourself. The part where you need some transformation from something to something else requires an example where there's some actual work to be done in the transformation).
